# Understanding the basic idea of Meteor Deps

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to understand the basic idea of the Meteor Deps tracking system.

```
var favoriteFood = "apples";
var favoriteFoodDep = new Deps.Dependency;

var getFavoriteFood = function () {
  favoriteFoodDep.depend();
  console.log(favoriteFood)
};

var setFavoriteFood = function (newValue) {
  favoriteFood = newValue;
  favoriteFoodDep.changed();
};


Template.jow.events({

  "click .showFavoriteFood":function(){

    setFavoriteFood("cloudy")

  }

})
```

So in this code i create a new Deps.Dependancy and i'm leaving a track in getFavoriteFood with favoriteFoodDep.depend().

Then in setFavoriteFood i call favoriteFoodDep.changed() to trigger the functions that depend on it.

So, what i'm expecting is that after setting setFavoriteFood (in the click event) and thus triggering the .changed() that all the functions that have the .depend() would trigger again and execute. In this case it would show "cloudy" in the console.

However, nothing is happening, why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only certain classes of function will rerun based on dependencies being invalidated.  From [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity):

> These Meteor functions run your code as a reactive computation:
>
> Templates, Deps.autorun, UI.render and UI.renderWithData

You're on almost the right lines, you just need to change your `setFavoriteFood` definition to the following:

```
var getFavoriteFood = function(newValue) {
    console.log(favoriteFood);
}

Deps.autorun(function(c) {
    favoriteFoodDep.depend();
    getFavoriteFood();
}
```

Obviously, in this simple case it would actually be more concise to do the logging within the `autorun` block, but as general practice I'd separate the logic that needs to be run reactively into a separate function, as above.  However, the essential summary is: if it's not in a `Deps.autorun`, then the `depend` method will have no effect.

**UPDATE**

One final thing to note is that the example you've quoted keeps the `depend()` method within the `getFavoriteFood` function, which will also work fine (i.e. you can nest your 'depend' method inside a function which is then called by the `Deps.autorun`).  I'd say there are pro's and con's to either approach, depending on the use case:

- If your `get` is going to be called from a variety of locations, it's probably best to keep the `depend` inside it as you will then be able to call it from any of the function classes above and it will be automatically reactive.
- If the function is a one/two/three-off use case then it can actually be more helpful to keep the `depend` in the `Deps.autorun` block so that it's immediately apparent what is being invalidated to make it rerun without having to work you way through nested function calls (which, from experience, can be quite hard work).

Comment: thx, that works, but why are the meteor folk putting up a wrong example: http://manual.meteor.com/#deps-asimpleexample . Here they don't add it to Deps.autorun()

Comment: You need to read down a couple of paragraphs!  The example at the top isn't yet reactive - they introduce the `Deps.autorun` immediately afterwards.